# can't use console in Linux

Tags: linux, linux-kernel

I have some problem with Linux, I switch graphic interface to the console using       Ctrl + Alt + Shift + F1, but I can't type  anything, every second I receive:
[image]

my question is, why can't I type anything in console, can I do something about that?

Answer (score 1):

It appears that hdc is experiencing some sort of error and the messages are overtaking the console. Techincally you can still type, but you will be unable to see the command you are typing. Ctrl+L should clear the screen and give you some ability to get something done.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like your system is using tty1 to display messages or syslog.  Or it's where `dmesg` is outputting kernel messages.  You could check `/etc/syslog.conf` or `/etc/inittab` for something that's referring to `/dev/tty1` to see if either of those are sending things there.  Don't remember how to tell which tty dmesg is using....

Anyhow, I would not use tty1 for anything.  It's been configured for diagnostic purposes in this case.  You have tty2+ available, and only one of those has X.

That said, the issue with tty1 is not the problem.  The problem is that `/dev/hdc` is reporting errors every second, and that's a lot more serious than "my tty1 has random output that keeps me from using it".  Google says the error is likely that the disk can't be initialized by the kernel.  In other words, your operating system is finding it impossible to talk to some of your hardware.  Unless hdc doesn't exist, you very likely have failing or failed hardware.

Answer (score 0):

Try CTRL+ALT+SHIFT+[F2 to F12]. One of them should open a new text console and one of them may take you back to your graphical ui